# Putting a timer on image rotation?

Tags: android

On Android(2.3.3), is it possible to make the rotation of an image not be instant?

The code example I used, from [here](http://www.androidpeople.com/android-image-rotate-example):

```
img=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.ImageView01);
Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.refresh);
// Getting width & height of the given image.
int w = bmp.getWidth();
int h = bmp.getHeight();
// Setting post rotate to 90
Matrix mtx = new Matrix();
mtx.postRotate(90);
// Rotating Bitmap
Bitmap rotatedBMP = Bitmap.createBitmap(bmp, 0, 0, w, h, mtx, true);
BitmapDrawable bmd = new BitmapDrawable(rotatedBMP);

img.setImageDrawable(bmd);
```

This rotation is instant, and I'd like to make the rotation visible. Is that possible in Android, or is that a Flash thing?

Comment: So you want to add a timer to the rotation of the image?

Comment: OP wants to delay the start of the animation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use a [ViewAnimation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/view-animation.html) on your imageview. Something like this is what you need:

in your res/anim folder:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<rotate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:fromDegrees="0" android:toDegrees="90"
    android:duration="2000" android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_decelerate_interpolator"
    android:startOffset="1000"
/>
```

Apply it to your view:

```
img.startAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context, R.anim.rotate));
```

You'll have to explore the different options and attributes on your own :)
[Here's a link to some more info.](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/animation-resource.html)

Comment: is it at all possible for the rotation to remain at its new location after having done the rotation? Now when it ends, it turns back to its original position.

Comment: Yes, use the fillAfter/fillEnabled parameters.

Comment: I opened a new question, because I actually need to do this not once, but once ever 3 seconds and in a specific direction(meaning specific angle): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8546449/

Answer (score 1):

If you want a delay before your image rotates you can check out AlarmManager. This should not be used to delay any animation as stated below in the comments by David Caunt.

If you want to animate the rotation you can check out RotateAnimation
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/RotateAnimation.html

Here is an example of rotating a text view, perhaps it can be helpful.
http://www.edumobile.org/android/android-programming-tutorials/rotating-text-animation/

Comment: Do *not* use AlarmManager - the Animation has built in support for delays using [startOffset](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/Animation.html#setStartOffset(long))!

Comment: Yes, I put AlarmManager in there because I thought the question was a bit confusing. It was hard to know if he wanted a delay for the rotation or if he wanted an animation. AlarmManager should only be used for recurring or scheduled tasks.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is call the same code again and rotating the image by 1 degree angle. By using the above method you really cant do any other way. But again if you try to trigger 1 degree by 1 degree at a rate of 25 frames per second it will not run smoothly in a tablet or mobile phone. You can try animations provided from android. But they apply animations for whole screen (as far as i know).